# hadoop hdfs migration from cdh3 to cdh4

Tags: hadoop, hbase, hdfs, microsoft-distributed-file-system

I have two hadoop clusters, My target is to use hadoop -cp to copy all the hdfs files from **cluster1** to **cluster2**

**Cluster1:**
Hadoop 0.20.2-cdh3u4

**Cluster2:**
Hadoop 2.0.0-cdh4.1.1

Now, even just running dfs -ls command against **cluster1** remotely on **cluster2** as below:

```
hadoop fs -ls hdfs://cluster1-namenode:8020/hbase
```

I am getting the exception:

**ls: Failed on local exception: java.io.IOException: Response is null.; Host Details : local host is: "cluster2-namenode/10.21.xxx.xxx"; destination host is: "cluster1-namenode":8020;**

I think it's due to the hadoop version difference, is there any workaround on this? My old environment-cluster1 doesn't have mapred deployed which rules out all the distcp, bhase copytable options. And the hbase replication ability is not available on cluster1 neither. I am struggling to think of a way to migrate the hdfs data from **cluster1** to **cluster2** since everybody is talking about upgrading cdh3 to cdh4 instead of migrating from 3 to 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Discussed this more in cloudera cdh user mailing thread:

https://groups.google.com/a/cloudera.org/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/cdh-user/GeT1RTbRVcw

In summary,

1. Regular DFS commands like `dfs -cp` between CDH3 and CDH4 will not work as both have different protocol versions (and are incompatible with one another over regular RPC calls).
2. Distcp can be used to copy hdfs data cross clusters even from cdh3 to cdh4, but a few prerequisites here: you need to run the distcp command on the cdh4 cluster, also cdh4 cluster needs to have mapred deployed/available. cdh3 cluster doesn't necessarily need mapred.
3. when running distcp command, do not use hdfs for the source path, use hftp for the source path while hftp for the destination path(since hftp is READ-ONLY, you will need write-access to the destination path) so the command looks like:

   hadoop distcp hftp://hadoop-namenode.cluster1/hbase hftp://hadoop-namenode.cluster2/hbase

Answer (score 1):

a few notes from my experience for Shengjie's answer:

1. it can be run from both CDH4 and CDH3, what matters is that the command is run on the destination cluster.
2. when running `distcp` commnad use `hftp` as source and `hdfs` as destination (since hftp is read only!) so the command looks like:

> hadoop distcp hftp://source.cluster1/path hdfs://destination.cluster1/path